# How to write slice by slice from nifti images in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I read nifti images by using matlab toolbox but how we can write slice by slice into another format like .jpg or png?
I try this like:

```
V=niftiread('Brats17_2013_2_1_flair.nii.gz');
imshow(V(:,:,1),[]);
imwrite(V,'test.jpg')
Error using imwrite (line 442)
Cannot write signed integer data to a JPEG file.
imwrite((V(:,:,1),[]),'test.jpg');
imwrite((V(:,:,1),[]),'test.jpg');

↑
Error: Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.
```

Answer (score 0):

just save the picture by "saveas" command. it worked correctly.

```
h = imshow(V(:,:,1),[]);
saveas (h,'test.jpg');
```

Good luck